# Why Do General Aviation Aircraft Cost So Much?

Tags: general-aviation, cost

Purchase price. Not total cost of ownership.

[This Aviation Question inspired mine.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36708/1798)

A quote [From this article in Flying Magazine](http://www.flyingmag.com/aircraft/pistons/cessna-172-still-relevant) (Dated 2012):

> Cessna is holding the line on pricing, but the new models still aren’t cheap. The 180 hp 172S, referred to by Cessna as the 172-SP goes for \$307,500 the 160 hp 172R sells for \$274,900.

---

Many years ago I heard this generalization: "half the cost of an airplane is litigation." And sure, I understand you should not replace a control surface cable with one from Home Depot. But still, these prices are breathtaking.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably a dupe. Question title words just didn't get that hit I guess

Comment: Just as an FYI, club/group ownership is another option to look at. Really spreads out the ownership costs and makes things affordable. I bought my "share" of a very well equipped, 1978 Cessna 177B Cardinal II for less than $8k. My cost per hour (wet) is less than the local school charges for its 152, and the airplane see's maybe 50 hours a year by all members.

Comment: [In reading the earlier answer:](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/24911/1798) I get a sense of a self fulfilling prophecy. Low volume because they cost too much. Then there's Less mgr. liability now. Then How many times does a 50 yr old design get certified anyway? Upgraded radio? How much certitude does that take? There's more gone into my car that a C-172 I think. Its not rocket surgery.

Comment: A lot of it is self-fulfilling prophecy. Also bear in mind that for your typical light GA single (say the Cessna 172 from your example) the purchase audience isn't generally individuals: They're selling these things to major flight training programs - often for much less than the "sticker price". Straight-line depreciation on a working airplane & the money they'll make when they sell it off in their next fleet refresh help soften the blow.